# How to store and re-use text input values and variable values that use Math.random()?

Tags: javascript, math, random, user-input

Okay, so I'm trying to create a quiz application for revision purposes that asks a random question from a list of questions, takes a text input as the users answer to the question, and then compares it to the actual answer to the question. The code I have used is:

```
var keyList = Object.keys(htmlModule);
var ranPropName = keyList[ Math.floor(Math.random()*keyList.length) ];
var pageStart = function() {
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = htmlModule[ranPropName][0];
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = answerValidation;
};
window.onload = pageStart;

var answerValidation = function(correctAnswer, userAnswer) {
    correctAnswer = htmlModule[ranPropName][1];
    userAnswer = document.getElementById("submit").value;;

    if(userAnswer === correctAnswer) {
    document.getElementById("rightWrong").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("rightWrong").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

};
```

The variable `htmlModule` refers to the object in which the questions and their answers are stored. Each question and answer pair is stored inside an array that is the value of its property, the property simply being a key used to reference each pair e.g. htmlQ1, htmlQ2 etc.

The main problem I seem to be having is that my `if` statement comparing the actual answer and the user answer won't evaluate to `true`. I know this because the background colour of the div element `rightWrong` only ever turns red, even when I've definitely typed in a correct answer at which point it should turn green. My assumption is that either the text input isn't being stored for some reason, or the value of the variable `ranPropName` that uses `Math.random()` is changing due to the use of `Math.method()`, but I'm stuck as to how to remedy either potential problem. Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Do some `console.log` troubleshooting. I'd assume it would be helpful to know what `userAnswer` is being set to, for example.

Comment: It makes no sense to have those two variables as parameters if you overwrite them anyway. Drop them from the parameter list and just use two `var`s in the function.

Comment: Please add a  `console.log(userAnswer, correctAnswer, typeof correctAnswer)` and show us the output. And give us an example of `htmlModule`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I started to visualize your quiz as you explained.

One thing is need to be changed is that you get `userAnswer` from the value of an element with Id `submit` which I assume most probably it's an button tag, so I write a working code sample as follow:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Title Goes Here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="rightWrong" />
    <div id="question" />
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    var htmlModule = {
      'htmlQ1': ['1+1=?', '2'],
      'htmlQ2': ['2+2=?', '4']
    };
    var keyList = Object.keys(htmlModule);
    var ranPropName = keyList[ Math.floor(Math.random()*keyList.length) ];
    var pageStart = function() {
      document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = htmlModule[ranPropName][0];
      document.getElementById("submit").onclick = answerValidation;
    };
    window.onload = pageStart;

    var answerValidation = function(correctAnswer, userAnswer) {
      correctAnswer = htmlModule[ranPropName][1];
      userAnswer = document.getElementById("rightWrong").value;

      if(userAnswer === correctAnswer) {
        document.getElementById("rightWrong").style.backgroundColor = "green";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("rightWrong").style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
    };
  </script>
</html>
```

Please share your html if you still face problems.

Comment: You were absolutely correct - I was accessing the value of the submit button rather than the text input element. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, man! And as the answer is useful, you can up vote it.

Comment: I already did, but it said that my reputation is too low for it to change the publicly displayed post score. I've only just made an account, but if I stick around long enough to gain a high enough reputation, i'll come back and up vote it again. Thanks again!